# How to create a .msi that installs in multiple locations with advanced installer

Tags: installation, advanced-installer

How to create a .msi that installs in multiple locations with advanced installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Advanced Installer forums you can easily find similar topics:

- [one file, multiple locations](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2901)
- [Multiple Install paths](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=23086)
- [custom install, multiple directories](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=5168)
- [Conditional Install location](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=26338)